# Parametric Equation of a Parabola give 3 points

Tags: functions, conic-sections, parametric

Good evening. How would I find the parametric equation of a parabola given three points? My point are endpoints $(-1, 2)$ and $(3, 4)$. However, the curve must also pass through $(0,0)$.

I have tried to solve in various ways using $x = at^2$ and $y = 2at$ but I keep going around in circles when I solve. I am really stumped.

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Gabrielle

Comment: What are “endpoints” of a parabola?

Comment: I think my teacher means the domain

Comment: Try $x = t, y = at^2 + bt$

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number of parabolas passing through these three points, so I’ll proceed assuming that the parabola’s axis is meant to be parallel to the $y$-axis.

Plug your points into the general equation $y=ax^2+bx+c$ one by one and solve for the unknown coefficients. So, you have $$a(-1)^2+b(-1)+c=a-b+c=2,$$ which means $c=2-a+b$. Next, you have $$a(0)^2+b(0)+c=2-a+b=0,$$ from which $b=a-2$ and thus $c=0$. Finally, $$a(3)^2+b(3)+c=9a+3(a-2)+0=12a-6=4$$ which yields $a=5/6$.

I expect that you’ll be able to come up with some parameterization from this Cartesian equation on your own.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinte parabolas passing through three points. But none of these have the $y$-axis as an axis.

The general equation of a parabola is $(Ax + By)^2+Cx+Dy+E=0$. Substituting $(-1,2)$, $(0,0)$, $(3,4)$, you can get any of the infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to perform the substitution - I am very confused about what to substitute in plus shouldn't myequations be in the form X= Y=.

Comment: Substituting $x=0$, $y=0$ gives $E=0$.

$x=-1$, $y=2$ gives $(-A+2B)^2-C+2D=0$.

$x=3$, $y=4$ gives $(3A+4B)^2+3C+4D=0$.

This system of equations for $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ has infinite solutions.